# When distinguishing 'in which' and 'which' is ambiguous

Tags: ambiguity

I'm a Korean high school student (who really likes reading English novels), and I'm curious regarding the usage of 'in which' and 'which' in a sentence. Which one do I have to use in the following sentence?

> There is clearly a point beyond (which/in which) running the exercise becomes running the art.

I thought that 'in which' would be better, but my teacher disagreed. Can't I use *in which* in this case?

Plus, since this is a sentence from a textbook written by Korean authors, I wonder if it has even the slightest awkwardness, when viewed from a native speaker.

Comment: You already have a preposition _beyond_ in that sentence, so adding an extra _in_ would be too much... I would not know how to parse the version with _in which_ for the sentence to make sense.

Answer (score -2):

> "There is clearly a point beyond **which** running the exercise becomes running the art."

Emphasis is on *point* as this usage of 'which' is non-conditional.

> "There is clearly a point beyond **in which** running the exercise becomes running the art."

Emphasis on the cause (running the exercise) as which in this case leads to something happening.

The 'in' implies the importance on the second part of the sentence, which can be rewritten as: *Running the exercise becomes running the art after a certain point.*

Another example would be:

> This is the kind of music **in which** he is interested.
>
> He is interested in this kind of music.

To make it more ambiguous, **in which** can be replaced by **where** but by doing this the emphasis/focus is returned to the first half of the statement.

> "There is clearly a point beyond **where** running the exercise becomes running the art."

The focus returns to 'a point'. **In which** implies that there is a specific point whereas **where** implies that there is *some* point, but it is not specific.

Another example:

> This is the box in which he keeps his wallet.
>
> This is the box where he keeps his wallet.

The first example focuses on the wallet. The second one focuses on *a* box which happens to be where he keeps his wallet.